# Why is the data in my object (when I try to log it out) undefined?

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

I am trying to log object data that I read from a QRCodeScanner.

```
<QRCodeScanner
    onRead={onSuccess}
    ref={scanner => setScanner(scanner)}
    flashMode={RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.auto}
  />
```

This is what onSuccess does:

```
const onSuccess = (e) => {
console.log(e.data)
setScanData(e.data)
}
```

This is what log out when I log e.data:

```
 {"user":{"date_created": 
 {"seconds":1674564456,"nanoseconds":000000000},"name":"Grant","data": 
 [{}],"email":"user@mail.com"}}
```

The problem comes in where I cant log a property or use a property inside the object. For example if I want to use, or log e.data.user it logs undefined or e.data.email it logs undefined. This data gets sent to storage and used later (it logs out the whole object) but I cant access any value inside the object. It always logs undefined.

Comment: Try to log the type of `e.data` (eg: `console.log(typeof e.data)`). Maybe it is a string not an object.

Comment: it is a string but I did try parsing it too (JSON.Parse())

Comment: It is `JSON.parse(..)` with lowercase **p**

Comment: I know, i made a typo in the comment

Comment: Do you get any errors when you run `JSON.parse(e.data)` ?

Comment: no I did not get any errors

Answer (score 1):

The `data` is in `e.user.data` not `e.data`.

Comment: e.user is undefined

Comment: What is `typeof e`?

Comment: it is an object.

Comment: and e.data is a string